# Why the different spellings of Belarus?

Tags: orthography, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire

In several poems in *Like Water, like Fire*, Belarus is spelled "Byelorussia", and in some it's spelled "Biełaruś". Why is that?

Comment: Biełaruś is probably the Polish spelling, given the letters ł and ś appearing there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology_of_Belarus